# On the usage of "of" and "for"?

Tags: prepositions

I am writing a report. In the middle of the report, I've written:

> Here, in order to reduce complexity we encounter in (33), we use approximation **of** the X. (The) Approximation **for** the X is given by:

The question is which preposition is correct, "for" or "of"?

Comment: BTW maybe you need to clean up your articles: "Here, in order to reduce **the** complexity we encounter in (33), we use **the** approximation of  X. **The** approximation for X is given by:" Now I need to think why this sounds more natural to me than your original revision . . .

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M You are right. it is more sensible since I have already mentioned the approximation. however, sb can say,"an approximation for the X is ..."

Comment: We need to know what noun or noun-phrase X stands for.  If you don't want to reveal the subject, perhaps you could paraphrase or substitute comparable nouns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- "...We use **an** approximation **of** X."" **The** approximation we use [**for** X]  is.....,.

square bracketed part is optional, because we already know whst it is an approximation of. But if used, "for" is the appropriate preposition.

Why?

The first sentence says that an approximation **OF** [the value of] X is *created*.  To approximate something is to make a reasonable estimation **of** its value.

The second sentence says that that approximation is then used **for** X (that is, in place of, or standing in **for**) X.

Answer (score 1):

"of" means "belonging to," or "associated with."

"for" means "on behalf of," or "for the benefit of"

In this case, the approximation is associated with, or belonging to, "the X."

Therefore, "of" is the correct usage.